# Linq Where Clause combined with Conditional

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I'm in a bit of problem here. I have an Linq statment that filters an list of objects from an Database.

Suppose I have the following list of elements(each '{...}' represents one object from the list):

```
{id: 288, id_price_table: 1},
{id: 295, id_price_table: 1},
{id: 295, id_price_table: 2},
{id: 295, id_price_table: 3}
```

And I have two paramters, One is 'StandardPriceTable' and the other one is 'CurrentUserPriceTable'. In my case these paramters are the following:

```
Int32 StandardPriceTable = 1;
Int32 CurrentUserPriceTable = 2;
```

Now what I want to achieve is: Make an where clause that takes the conditional if the id is unique (and thus belongs to the StandardPriceTable) it returns the current object to the list.

But if the same ID belongs to lots of id_price_table than it should verify which one of the objects belongs to CurrentUserPriceTable returning **only** that object excluding others with the same ID.

I know I can achieve this with a foreach statement but that would cause an database query that I want to avoid by the time being.

Based on the conditions I've told **the result** of the query would equals to:
**IQueryable** with the following itens:

```
{id: 288, id_price_table: 1},
{id: 295, id_price_table: 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var result = from item in Items
             group item by item.Id into g
             select g.Single(i => g.Count() == 1 ? 
                                  true : 
                                  i.Id_price_table == CurrentUserPriceTable);
```

---

or using lambdas:

```
var result2 = Items.GroupBy(i => i.Id)
                   .Select(g => g.Single(i => g.Count() == 1 ? 
                                              true : 
                                              i.Id_price_table == CurrentUserPriceTable));
```

Comment: Can you translate this to lambda representation? This won't cause an Database query to happen?

Comment: Dominic Thanks that solved my problem. I just had to adjust the "single" method to 'firstordefault'.

Could you explain the select part with the single method? I'm kinda new here, and struggling.

Comment: @MarcosSantini If you want literally *single* result or `null` if there is no elements or more than one, then use `SingleOrDefault`. `FirstOrDefault` should be used when want the first element (when more than one are possible) or `null` when sequence is empty.

Comment: As a matter of fact, your answer don't automaticaly triggers the query to happen. The triggers seems to happen only when I try to access the data with an foreach in the View.

Comment: @MarcosSantini Yes. This is called *deffered execution*; the Linq query is really just a *query*, and the execution only happens if you execute the query (by using `foreach` or other kinds of iteration).

Comment: @DominicKexel I know that, I asked if your anwser caused the query to execute, and you said yes. The real answer to that is No, it only executes when we ask the query to happen.

Comment: @MarcosSantini You're right, my comment was not very clear about that.